# Pass multiple arguments from Django template for loops into Django template filter or tag

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm building a timetable application and I need to check if there is a certian room available so
I want to create a function/template tag/template filter to return me a boolean value which I want to later on pass into Django template if statement.

View function:

```py
def my_view(request):
    args = {
        'days': Days.objects.all(),
        'times': Times.objects.all(),
        'rooms': Rooms.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request, 'my_page', args)
```

Template stucture example that I need:

```
{% for day in days %}
    {% for time in times %}
        {% for room in rooms %}
            {% if MY_TAG {{ day }} {{ time }} KWARG={{ room }} %}
                <p>SOMETHING IF TRUE</p>
            {% else %}
                <p>SOMETHING IF FALSE</p>
            {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I've looked on the official Django docs, SO and other sites and forums for these things. I've found a couple of promising code examples that didn't work but gave me the idea of structure concept for my function.

- [Official Django docs 1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags)
- [Official Django docs 2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/)
- [Stack Overflow 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998912/django-templatetag-return-true-or-false)
- [Stack Overflow 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420703/how-to-add-multiple-arguments-to-my-custom-template-filter-in-a-django-template)

The function that I have so far is working but I can't implement it in Django template.

My function/template tag:

```py
from ..models import Timetables
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def check_availability(day, time, **kwargs):
    if variable == 'room':
        if Timetables.objects.filter(day=day, time=time, room=kwargs['room']).exists():
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: Do not put complicated logic in your templates. Your business logic should go in the view.

Comment: How should I do it then? I need a template that generates a empty timetable where I can fill in some information one of which is in which room will your class be. I need to check if that room is in use at that specific day in that specific time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a partial answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791531/if-else-custom-template-tag). I can use the keyword `as` to store the value that my template tag `check_availability` returns into a variable called `room_available` which I can later use in an if statement.

```
{% check_availability day time room=room as room_available %}
{% if room_available %}
    <p>SOMETHING IF TRUE</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you found everything you needed by yourself, you can add the `as XXX` to store the result of a tag as context variable

```
{% for day in days %}
    {% for time in times %}
        {% for room in rooms %}
            {% MY_TAG day time room=room as res %}
            {% if res %}
                <p>SOMETHING IF TRUE</p>
            {% else %}
                <p>SOMETHING IF FALSE</p>
            {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

It is very similar to a python function, `day` and `time` will be resolved as context value and passed as first and second arguments. `room` will also be resolved as context value but passed as a keyword argument behind the keyword `room`

Comment: It doesn't work because I cannot put tag in an if statement. That is where I have problems. `{% check_availability day time room=room %}` this is how I can call the function/template tag but I need it to return True/False value so I can display things based on the result.

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood your issue. As you found, you can store the result with an as statement